# ifelse() behavior and related error: incompatible types in subassignment type fix (R)

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to run a `ifelse()` command but getting some weird behavior...

Running:

```
1 <= 50
```

I get:

> TRUE

Where `typeof(1 <= 50)` and `class(1 <= 50)` returns

> [1] "logical"

However, once I put this into a `ifelse()` loop I get some weird behavior...

```
ifelse(1 <= 50, print("Yay"), print("Boo"))
```

> [1] "Yay"

> [1] "Yay"

It prints the true condition action twice....

I am thinking this is the reason I get this error:

> Error in ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos] :
> incompatible types (from S4 to logical) in subassignment type fix

When I write more complicated code:

```
ifelse(length(List[[1]]) >= 50, List[[1]][1], print("Error"))
```

Which is interesting because if I have the yes statement`ifelse()` assign something to a variable, I still get the error but the resulting object is correct....

```
> ifelse(length(List[[1]]) >= 50, test <- List[[1]][1], print("Error"))
> test
```

What am I not understanding....

Comment: I can use a normal if() {} else{} here too, but i was using ifelse() under the impression that it is preferred/quicker. I am also not sure if this is true.

Comment: `print` doesn't have a return value `ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same `length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are slightly misunderstanding the purpose of `ifelse()`: this function is made to pick elements from either of two vectors/matrices.  The online help describes it as follows:

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
> with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
> element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

Using arguments with side effects is allowed, but somewhat odd.  I believe you should use `if ... else` for your case.

So what is going on for `ifelse(1 <= 50, print("Yay"), print("Boo"))`?  The first argument is a number (vector of length 1) with just the value `TRUE`.  So `ifelse()` returns a single element.  Since the value is `TRUE`, it gets the value from the second argument.  This prints `"Yay"`, but also returns `"Yay"` to the `ifelse()` function.  This returned `"Yay"` is then selected as the output and returned from the `ifelse()` call.  After the call completes, this result is printed to the terminal, giving you the second line of `"Yay"`.

Comment: Yea I was reading the help and it didnt make sense. I thought logicals didnt have a shape or shape is 1, so that I could output 1 list/data.frame/vector or a list/data.frame/vector of length 1 >_<"

But ok, this makes more sense now. ifelse() is only really useful for single value output. Would it ever be used for something else (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: @SkyScraper I only ever use it for vectors.  For example in `ifelse(x < 3, x, y)`, the first argument is a logical (boolean) vector with the same length as x, and the call returns a vector which has elements taken from `x` (where `x < 3`) and `y` (otherwise).